# MySQL extract gender as a string when it stored in the table as a Boolean

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `accounts`.
There I have a column called `gender` where it's data type is `Boolean`.

I want to directly get the gender as a string in my `select` `query`.
How do I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: Do you really want/need to store a binary gender? You might be better off to store a salutation or Similiar data and be prepared for „don’t want to say“ or „address gender neutral“ or Similiar. Besides that you can turn a Boolean or integer with `CASE WHEN` to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySql supports the standard SQL CASE statement. MySQL also has the shorter, but non-standard IF statement

```
SELECT IF(gender,'MALE','FEMALE') as gender from accounts
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use a `case when expression`

```
select *, case when gender=false then 'Female' else 'Male' end as gender
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select gender,IF(gender=1,"Male","Female") as gender2 from accounts
```